# What is the best way to condense this code? It's functional but not very DRY

Tags: jquery, dry

This jQuery works just fine, but there has got to be an easier way to achieve the same result with less code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ce").click(function() {
    $("#dot2, #dot3, #dot4, #logo").hide();
    $("#dot1").fadeToggle();
  });
  $("#regs").click(function() {
    $("#dot1, #dot4, #dot3, #logo").hide();
    $("#dot2").fadeToggle();
  });
  $("#pmp").click(function() {
    $("#dot1, #dot2, #dot4, #logo").hide();
    $("#dot3").fadeToggle();
  });
  $("#emr").click(function() {
    $("#dot1, #dot2, #dot3, #logo").hide();
    $("#dot4").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="dots">
    <div id="dot1" class="dot">text</div>
    <div id="dot2" class="dot">text</div>
    <div id="dot3" class="dot">text</div
    <div id="dot4" class="dot">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your html?

Comment: you can chain selectors ... you could also make a function

Comment: Is that the OP's actual HTML, or did someone else make that up?

Comment: @ziggywiggy it's the OPs own. They placed it in a comment which was then edited in to the question.

Answer (score 3):

To DRY this up you can use a combination of common classes to unify the logic to be applied to the elements and make selecting them easier, and also data attributes to store the custom metadata on the individual elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));
    $('.dot').not($target).hide();
    $target.fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#dots > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle" data-target="dot1">1</button>
<button class="toggle" data-target="dot2">2</button>
<button class="toggle" data-target="dot3">3</button>
<button class="toggle" data-target="dot4">4</button>

<div id="dots">
  <div id="dot1" class="dot">Dot1</div>
  <div id="dot2" class="dot">Dot2</div>
  <div id="dot3" class="dot">Dot3</div>
  <div id="dot4" class="dot">Dot4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  let target = $("#dot2, #dot3, #dot4, #logo");
  function toggle(except) {
    target.not(except).hide();
    $(except).fadeToggle();
  }
  $("#ce").click(function(){
    toggle("#dot1");
  });
  $("#regs").click(function(){
    toggle("#dot2");
  });
  $("#pmp").click(function(){
    toggle("#dot3");
  });
  $("#emr").click(function(){
    toggle("#dot4");
  });
});
```

After knowing the HTML:

Same :) because I don't know where your #ce, #regs, #pmp and #emr are

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of the IDs that get the click handler, and use the index to target the proper `dot` and its siblings.

```js
var clicks = ["ce", "regs", "pmp", "emr"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  clicks.forEach((id, i) => {
    $("#" + id).click(e => {
      $("#dot" + (i + 1))
        .fadeToggle()
        .siblings()
        .add("#logo")
        .hide();
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dots">
  <div id="dot1" class="dot">text</div>
  <div id="dot2" class="dot">text</div>
  <div id="dot3" class="dot">text</div>
  <div id="dot4" class="dot">text</div>
</div>
```